# Ubuntu 15.04 Visual Glitches

Tags: boot, grub2, graphics, 15.04

I reinstalled Ubuntu 15.04 onto my computer, and I am receiving some strange graphical/visual glitches when I boot up. First off, there is some black terminal grub screen that comes up, tells me my graphics card, then quits. Then my motherboard screen comes up (that's fine) Then it flashes the purple Ubuntu screen. After that it says booting in insecure mode (That's not supposed to happen, right?) And finally the 2 most confusing parts. Instead of the Ubuntu loading screen, there are just dots in the middle of the screen, and the rest is black (besides a purple line). [image]

**Update:**

```
  sudo update-grub
  sudo reboot now
```

**That got rid of the purple line, but rest is still there**

Then, after I get to the login screen, and type in my password, the following happens[image]

It goes from that back to the normal screen. These have no physical effect on the computer, but are still VERY annoying, and I would like to fix them, anyone know how?
I've read that it might be because of my graphics card drivers, so here is my graphics card:

```
  david@david-desktop:~$ lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.[AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 300b
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

So I did

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

and that should've fixed it, but it didn't.
Help please!